# PHP Email issues

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to send `form` data to an email, but it's not working properly. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

    $to = "someemail@thisplace.com";
    $subject = "Contact Us";
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['comment/questions'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
    $headers = "From: $email";
    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if ($sent) {
        print "Your Comments/Questions have been sent. Thank You!";
    } else {
        print "We encountered an error sending your Comments/Questions!";
    }

?>
```

Comment: And... what's your question?

Comment: what is wrong with my code, why doesn't it work

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not doing anything with the entered name and phone number?

Comment: well i ran a test and it didnt send the email to the places i declared. I would like to use all the information but i dunno how to call it back properly and send it

Answer (score 0):

It's important to realize that you also need a mechanism to actually send the email from your computer. PHP itself is not capable of doing so (I think so anyway). If I understand this correctly PHP 'just' passes the information to mail server (which then actually sends an email).

If you have any further details about your problem, do share - error messages (if any), what have you tried etc...

Answer (score 0):

TomasH is right.  PHP sends the outgoing message using a local SMTP server.  In your php.ini, check the value of sendmail_path.  This will show you what PHP is using to send the message.  Most likely, it is sendmail, qmail, postfix, etc.  Then, you can check this mail server's logs to see 1) whether on not the mail server received the outgoing message from your PHP script, and if so, 2) what happened when the mail server tried to deliver the message to the recipient's mail server.